# Flutter : Issue with the dependencies in the project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dependencies

I am using a prebuilt project and I am getting below issue with the three dependencies mentioned

> Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following
> dependencies don't support null safety:
>
> - package:place_picker
> - package:chips_choice
> - package:location

Answer (score 1):

Replace these three packages with

1. place_picker: ^0.9.20-nullsafety
2. chips_choice_null_safety: ^2.0.6
3. location: ^4.3.0

All supports null safely. These versions as latest/pre-release as per May 5, 2022. Versions might get updated in future.